# Force qtip to only appear when element is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I used the qtip plugin. I write the qtip code

```
.on('click', '.selectionOptions', function(){
    $('.selectionOptions').qtip({
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-component-config selectionOpt',
            tip: false
        },
        content: {
            text: 'Hai'
        }
    });
})
```

This qtip is intended to appear when I will click the `.selectionOptions` `div`.
However this qtip is appearing while I hover the `div`. How can I rectify this problem using jQuery.

Comment: bind a hover event to the element and use event.preventDefault()

Comment: i used the qtip2 plugin.

Comment: You attach qTip only _after_ the element is clicked. Bind it _before_... Meaning remove the very first and very last line of the above code, problem solved.

Comment: i want to display the qtip after i click the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For qTip 2 you can use

```
show: {
        event: 'click'
    }
```

Full example (from the documentation page):

```
$('.selector').qtip({
    suppress: false,
    content: {
        text: 'You must have known to click me from the browser tooltip...!?'
    },
    show: {
        event: 'click'
    }
})
.attr('title', 'Click me to show a qTip!'); // Apply a title attribute to the elements
```

Have  a look on the documentation here: http://qtip2.com/options#core.suppress

Comment: can you post your code with this solution of a fiddle?